# How to resolve the issue of No response from server in asmack when create MUC Group Some times?

Tags: android, asmack, xmp

I am developing a one chat application in this i am using asmack library, this code for creating Muc room.

```
public void createGroup(String group){

    String[] temp=group.split("/");
    String groupName=temp[0];
    String unique=temp[1];
    System.out.println("Group_name!!!"+groupName);
    System.out.println("Unique!!!" + unique);
    try {
        MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(mXMPPConnection, unique + "@muc.202.65.158.173");
        // For Providing Nick Name To Conference.
        AndFilter var7 = new AndFilter(new PacketFilter[]{new FromMatchesFilter((unique+"@muc.202.65.158.173").toLowerCase() + "/" + groupName), new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class)});
        PacketCollector var8 = this.mXMPPConnection.createPacketCollector(var7);
        Presence var5 = (Presence)var8.nextResult((long)SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
       /* if(var5 == null){
            Log.e("NEW EROOR:","Catch the Error");
        }else {*/
            mMultiUserChat.create(groupName);
            //setConfig(mMultiUserChat, groupName);
            String userjID = mConfig.userName + "@" + mConfig.server;
            for (int i = 0; i < NewGroupWindow.selectedjids.length; i++) {
                mMultiUserChat.invite(NewGroupWindow.selectedjids[i], "Please join this room");
            }
            System.out.println("Room Created!!!");
            mMultiUserChat.join(userjID);
            mMultiUserChat.changeSubject(groupName);
            new GetGroups().execute();
        //}

    }
    catch(XMPPException xe){

    }
 }
```

This is code for creating room and invite the members to the group.
The above code is working perfectly, some times it's showing "No response from server". 
Please give me any idea how to resolve this

Thanks...